# Multiple $query = mysql_query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check for duplicate usernames and check if they already exist in the database or not. If they do, I show them an error message.

I am doing it with username but I also need to do it with the email address.

Here's my code so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username='".$username."'");
```

...

```
else if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
    {
        echo "<p><b><center> <font color=\"red\">Username already exists.<br> </b>If you already have an account, please<a href = '../user/login.php'> click here </a> to login.</font></center></p>"; 
    }
```

**My question is** how can I do the same for email? Do I need to have one another query for email so like `$query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email='".$email."'");` and add it after the first query in the above code?

I tried doing it but it gives me an error.
Thanks.

Comment: **Building SQL statements with outside variables makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.** Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like "O'Malley", will blow up your query. Learn about parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) has many detailed examples. See also http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives & explanation of the danger. Running SQL statements built with outside data is like eating soup made from ingredients found on your doorstep.

Comment: Why don't you just insert the record? If it fails due to constraints you know there was already such a record. This assumes you have unique constraints set up already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT({$field}) AS n FROM Users WHERE {$field}='{$value}';");
$tuple = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($tuple['n'] > 0) {
    $dup = true;
    break;
}
```

This is what you are looking for. But be careful, it is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: You should have copy-pasted the definition of `$fields` from my own answer too, or the code has little chance of working; you'd just get a "$fields is undefined" message, and a SQL error if the script doesn't stop.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to run multiple queries; you could benefit from indexing and better maintainability.

**You should not use mysql_* functions; they are deprecated and will soon be removed**. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead (or `mysqli`).

That said, at least escape your values in order to **avoid SQL injection**, or good faith errors if someone has a name with a quote - D'Artagnan, or O'Brien. The code below is not proof against *all* problems, but can intercept the most common ones. Again, PDO and prepared queries would help you no end:

```
// Fields to check for duplicate.
$fields = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $email
);

$dup = false;
foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT({$field}) AS n FROM Users WHERE {$field}='{$value}';");
    $tuple = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    if ($tuple['n'] > 0) {
        $dup = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($dup) {
    echo "<p><b><center> <font color=\"red\">{$field} already exists.<br> </b>If you already have an account, please<a href = '../user/login.php'> click here </a> to login.</font></center></p>"; 
}
```

The use of `COUNT()` instead of retrieving the query count could be slightly more efficient depending on indexing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it. You are the first person on the site who has helped me by actually putting it into my code and stuff. Thanks :)

Comment: You're most welcome. But please *do* consider switching to PDO. We don't say that just to look cool, honest :) -- and trust me, you so do **not** want to plug a _POST or _GET variable straight into a query, *ever*. Check out the site suggested by @AndyLester - http://bobby-tables.com/ .